# DIDL XML conversion to HTML using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a very specific XML file of DIDL, which somewhat looks like this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Item_Declaration_Language

I want to convert this into HTML using XSLT which should have expand and collapse feature also. I tried many things but couldn't find any solution.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: sample Input and desired Output XML are expected.

Answer (score 1):

apart from a specific namespace declaration, it is indeed a regular XML.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<did:DIDL xmlns:did="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2002:02-DIDL-NS" xmlns:didmodel="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2002:02-DIDMODEL-NS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <did:Item>
    <did:Descriptor>
      <did:Statement mimeType="text/plain">Image item which two images</did:Statement>
    </did:Descriptor>
    <did:Descriptor>
      <did:Component>
        <did:Resource mimeType="image/png" ref="http://imagearchive.net/path/image.png"/>
      </did:Component>
    </did:Descriptor>
    <did:Choice choice_id="choice1" minSelections="1" maxSelections="1" default="selection1">
      <did:Descriptor>
        <did:Statement mimeType="text/plain">Choice for selection of image 1 or 2. Digital items do not need to have choices.</did:Statement>
      </did:Descriptor>
      <did:Selection select_id="selection1">
        <did:Descriptor>
          <did:Statement mimeType="text/plain">Selection 1</did:Statement>
        </did:Descriptor>
      </did:Selection>
    </did:Choice>
    <did:Component>
      <did:Condition require="selection1" />
      <did:Descriptor>
        <did:Statement mimeType="text/plain">Picture 1 text summary</did:Statement>
      </did:Descriptor>
      <did:Resource mimeType="plain/text">This is a plain text resource which is a text about picture 1</did:Resource>
    </did:Component>
    <did:Component>
      <did:Condition require="selection1" />
      <did:Descriptor>
        <did:Statement mimeType="text/plain">Picture 1 text#1</did:Statement>
      </did:Descriptor>
      <did:Descriptor>
        <!-- the statement also can contain XML -->
        <did:Statement mimeType="text/plain">Picture 1 text#2</did:Statement>
      </did:Descriptor>
      <did:Resource mimeType="image/jpg" ref="http://picturedatabase.com/path/image1.jpg"/>
      <did:Resource mimeType="image/jpg" ref="http://picturedatabasemirror.com/path/image1.jpg"/>
    </did:Component>
    <did:Component>
      <did:Descriptor>
        <did:Statement mimeType="text/plain">Picture 2 text#2</did:Statement>
      </did:Descriptor>
      <did:Resource mimeType="image/jpg" ref="http://picturedatabase.com/path/image1.jpg"/>
      <did:Resource mimeType="image/jpg" ref="http://picturedatabasemirror.com/path/image1.jpg"/>
    </did:Component>
  </did:Item>
</did:DIDL>
```

Below is an XSL code, with just Identical template.. Output will be as same as Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:did="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below code replaces element `<did:Descriptor/>` with `<did:CustomElement/>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:did="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2002:02-DIDL-NS">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node()[local-name() = 'Descriptor']">
    <xsl:element name="did:CustomElement">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: but i want to implement expand and collapse feature also in this and the output should in form of html and a tree view, not xml

Comment: @user1402867, (1) you are most welcome. (2) then you have to post sample input XML and desired HTML output. Try something on your end, post those here, get the answers.

Comment: my xml looks like this - `code`
Part 1- 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="n.xsl"?>
<DIDL xmlns="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2002:02-DIDL-NS"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:dii="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2002:01-DII-NS"
xmlns:abc="http://www.google.com/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Container>
<Descriptor>
<Statement mimeType="text/plain">hello</Statement>
</Descriptor>
<Container>
<Descriptor>
<Statement mimeType="text/plain">hii</Statement>
</Descriptor>

Comment: part 2 - `code`
<Item>
<Descriptor>
<Statement mimeType="text/xml">
<abc:file>
<abc:id>3</abc:id>
<abc:name>new</abc:name>
<abc:ver>300000000</abc:version>
</abc:file>
</Statement>
</Descriptor>
<Component>
<Descriptor>
<Statement mimeType="text/plain">hello again</Statement>
</Descriptor>
<Resource mimeType="application/pdf" ref="test.pdf"></Resource>
</Component>
</Item> 
</Container>
</Container>
</DIDL>

Comment: output i want is like this
- Hello
  - hii
    - 3
    - new
    - 3000000 

the output is form of a tree which should have collapse and expand feature

Comment: i am sorry i dnt know why this formatting is like this over here, if you will run the xml i think u will understand how i want the output

Comment: @user1402867, great! you could have updated this code in question itself. Why take so trouble updating in comment. Meanwhile let me take time and study your requirement.

Comment: @user1402867, when you say **output should have collapse and expand feature!** Do you mean something like DOM? you want output to be XML or HTML or what else??

Comment: thanks for your reply again! See the output should be in html and in a tree form. it should first display hello then inside it hii and inside hii sub links should be 3 new 300000. yeah i mean the kind of DOM tree

Comment: any solution for the problem?